# all_equal: Can't join because of incompatible types (list / list)

Tags: r, dataframe, jsonlite

I have a data.frame, created from JSON format. It contains arrays of simple types, which are by default represented as a list of single vector. Then in unit tests I try to check it with `dplyr::all_equal` (I don't care about column order now, they get reordered by `jsonlite::flatten` and I don't have any idea how to deal with that).

But `all_equal` fails with a not very helpful message `Can't join on 'arr' x 'arr' because of incompatible types (list / list)`. I don't know what is wrong - is `list` not acceptable at all? Should I convert this column to something else? (what?)

Minimal example showing what I'm trying to do:

```
f <- function() {
    current <- jsonlite::fromJSON('{"objs":[{"arr":["l1", "l2"], "key":"1"}]}')$objs
    expected <- data.frame("key" = "1", stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
        mutate("arr" = list(c("l1", "l2")))

    str(current)
    str(expected)

    all_equal(current, expected, ignore_col_order = TRUE)
}

f()
```

Output:

```
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ key: chr "1"
 $ arr:List of 1
  ..$ : chr  "l1" "l2"
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ key: chr "1"
 $ arr:List of 1
  ..$ : chr  "l1" "l2"
 Error: Can't join on 'arr' x 'arr' because of incompatible types (list / list)
```

*Note:* I've seen [How to fix “Error: Can't join on '.rows' x '.rows' because of incompatible types (list / list)” using censReg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56075390/how-to-fix-error-cant-join-on-rows-x-rows-because-of-incompatible-types), but I don't think I have this issue, because the data frames are not grouped. I tried to ungroup them both anyway, there was no change in output.

Comment: I'd also be happy with a way to flatten nested data frames without changing column order (which would make me use `all.equal` rather than `all_equal`), but that seems out of scope for this question.

Comment: using `all.equal` I get `TRUE` but get the error when using `all_equal`. Are you after `all.equal` or `all_equal`?

Comment: @Onyambu I wanted `all_equal` to ignore order of columns, because `jsonlite::flatten` does reorder them. I'll edit question to reflect that better (a case where `all.equal` will return `FALSE`)

Comment: It seems that `all_equal()` won't work with data frames that contain nested elements.  If you unnest first it works `list(current, expected) %>% map(unnest, arr) %>% {all_equal(.[[1]], .[[2]])}`.